# How do I check form elements in HTML before the form has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm using PHP to validate and run my form, however, I want to check elements as they are filled out. How do I check an element for its current value prior to the submission of the form?

Comment: However you do it make sure you validate in your PHP too, to allow for users with no JavaScript (and users who deliberately bypass your client-side validation).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760249/custom-javascript-validation/3760297#3760297. You can use a similar approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents have a [forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064) collection, forms have an [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) collection, elements that are form controls have associated DOM properties such as *value*, *checked*, *selected* and so specified in their related interfaces (e.g. [HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025), [HTMLSelectElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980)) that can be compared to allowed values and ranges.

There are many, many questions and articles on the subject. Search for form validation, have a go, ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript to validate the data in the form without sending it to the server.

http://www.elated.com/articles/form-validation-with-javascript/ may be useful

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: either validat it with javascript before the form is submitted, or you check by PHP on the page it has been submitted to. usually it is wise to do both, in case javascript is turned off.